# The best implementation of a tableview in Model View Controller

Tags: swift, uitableview, model-view-controller, uiview, uiviewcontroller

What is the best implementation of a tableview in Model View Controller?
 I'm developing my app without storyboard, all programmatically .

Is it possible to implement a TableView in a UIView? I tried it, but If I implement the TableView in a view, when the controller recives a button action, I can't modify or access to the tableView of the View...

After that, I tried to implement the tableView in a ViewController and it works perfectly, but I don't know if this is a good implementation because I found the same problem when I wanted to implement a TextView/TextField with a Piker, for example.

My goal was to had a clean code of viewController with a views and controllers (of buttons etc) and now I find myself with a uiviewController with the view and multiples components when I wanted the components were in the corresponding views.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Its definitely possible. Could you include some of your code where you tried to implement it inside a UIView. Perhaps then we can give specific ideas to help :)

Answer (score 0):

It is all possible, and the problems you are running into are not because of it being something that you should not do, but that it is something that inherently works slightly differently than before. To answer your question directly, I would implement the tableView as the modal view controller directly, either as a UITableViewController or a UIViewController that inherits the table views delegate and datasource (this method being chosen if you don't want the table view to use up the entirety of the modal view controller's space).

TableViews are simple to use, but understanding every detail of how they work will make you far stronger and able to use them in any of these scenarios. I am not going to write you a guide on their use, butcontinue studying them before you declare that anything "can not be done".

Knowing what classes to implement the delegate methods becomes very important during these different scenarios. It is often easiest to use textfields delegate's implementation in UITableViewCell's subclass rather than in the UIViewController they are in. This allows for a more modular creation.

I find that working with the storyboard allows for a much quicker learning curve, and also a time saver. The one excuse I will give you for working without a storyboard is if you have an extremely slow computer.